# facing issues in lower versions of android like 2.3.5 in application made through phonegap 2.9.0

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm developing an application in phonegap, in which I use functionality from Google Drive like upload file, download file, create folder, etc. My application is working fine on version 4 and greater Android versions.

But in lower version (like 2.3.5) when I delete any file, upload any file, rename any file it gets updated on server, but when I call web service it gives older response of data, but on greater than 4 it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I actually had the same problem
the solution is a bit weird.

The issue lies in the browser version, the android native browser in android version below 4.0 behaves kinda like IE, so it caches everything, so in order to get your application to work correctly you have to send no caching headers back to the application from your server requests:

```
// HTTP 1.1.
res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")

// HTTP 1.0.
res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")

// Proxies.
res.setHeader("Expires", 0)
```